# how to use dataframe name inside for loop to save different ggplot2 plots in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a data frame (all.table) that i have subsetted into 3 different data plots name (A1.table, B25.table, and C48.table)

```
all.table = read.table(file.path(input_file_name), header=T, sep = "\t")
A1.table = subset(all.table, ID == "A1")
B25.table = subset(all.table, ID == "B25")
C48.table = subset(all.table, ID == "C48")
```

For each graph type I want, I want to generate it based on all 4 tables

```
for (i in list(all.table, A1.table, B25.table, C48.table)){
    ggplot(i, aes(x=Position, fill=Frequency)) + #other plot options
    ggsave(file.path(full_output_path, "uniqueFileName.pfd")
    #additional plots
    #additional saves
    }
```

my problem comes in the ggsave command with how to generate the 'uniqueFileName.pdf'. I would like to name it as some form of all.table.graph1.pdf, all.table.graph2.pdf and A1.table.graph1.pdf, A1.table.graph2.pdf etc

My question is how do I turn the name of the iterator `i` into a string, and add that string to a `'.graph1.pdf'` string?

Coming from a python background this seems like it should be rather simple. I am not very versed in R (as is likely obvious from this question) and anything resembling an answer I have found seems incredibly over complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution by looking for a python dictionary equivalent:

```
all.table = read.table(file.path(input_file_name), header=T, sep = "\t")
A1.table = subset(all.table, ID == "A1")
B25.table = subset(all.table, ID == "B25")
C48.table = subset(all.table, ID == "C48")

#Generate a named list of tables
list_of_tables = list(all = all.table, A1 = A1.table, B25 = B25.table, C48 = C48.table)

for (i in 1:length(list_of_tables)){
    ggplot(list_of_tables[[i]], aes(x=Frequency, fill=Category)) + #more options
    ggsave(file.path(full_output_path, paste0(names(list_of_tables[i]), ".graph1.pdf"))
    }
```

I'm not sure if there is a downside to not using other libraries (ie `tidyverse`), but this seems like the simplest answer?

Comment: If those three IDs exhaust all possible IDs, consider `by` or `split` and avoid saving those subset tables in memory: `split(all.table, all.table$ID)` or `by(all.table, all.table$ID, identity)`. In fact, these both create named lists of subsetted dfs and for `by`, replace *identity* with a function to run through your `ggplot` calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workflow that uses the `tidyverse` suite of functions.  `iwalk` is similar to `lapply` in base, but it requires a function that takes 2 arguments, and it automatically inputs the names of the list as the 2nd argument.
The short answer for what you want is `paste0`, which lets you combine strings.

```
library(tidyverse)
all.table %>%
  filter(ID %in% c("A1", "B25", "C48")) %>% # only needed if there are more IDs than the 3 explictly listed
  split(., .$ID) %>% # creates the list of data frames
  c(list(all.table = all.table), .) %>% # adds "all.table" as a list element
  iwalk(function(df, label) {
    ggplot(df, aes(x = Position, fill = Frequency)) + 
      ...
    ggsave(file.path(full_output_path, paste0(label, ".graph1.pdf")))
  })
```